# Postgres authentication failing when running TypeORM migration

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, docker, typeorm

I am using Docker for my Node app. I was using `synchronize` in `ormconfig.ts` but want to switch to using migrations. I am able to bring up the app with `docker-compose up....` just fine. And I can connect to the database with `docker-compose exec db psql....` and query the database, so I know the environment variables for `PGDATABASE`, `PGUSER`, `PGPASSWORD`, etc. are set fine. But for some reason, when I run `npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n migration-name` or `npm run typeorm migration:run` I'm getting

```
Error during migration generation:
error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I added logging to `ormconfig.ts` -

```
console.log(
  `Connecting to ${process.env.PGDATABASE} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} with user ${process.env.PGUSER}, password ${process.env.PGPASSWORD}`
)
```

and the env vars are correct. Are there some other configuration options I need to set somewhere else for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. `ormconfig.ts` needs to have the local port for the db, not the port in the container. In docker-compose.yml:

```
    ports:
      - "4420:5432"
```

(because I have multiple database containers). So in `ormconfig.ts` I needed to change the port to 4420. Now it works.